# I can not display the labels in JQChart?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help, how to get a pie chart title triangles instead of percentages.
The documentation for this example, considered very fast, without using text instead of numbers.

**I have a code:**

```
                $('#jqChart').jqChart({
                    legend: { visible: false },
                    animation: { duration: 1 },
                    series: [
                        {
                            type: 'pie',
                            fillStyles: ['#418CF0', '#FCB441', '#E0400A', '#056492', '#BFBFBF'],
                            labels: {
                                stringFormat: '%s',
                                valueType: 'dataValue',
                                font: '15px sans-serif',
                                fillStyle: 'white'
                            },
                            data: [['N', 65], ['A', 58], ['B', 30],
                                ['F', 60], ['C', 65]]
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

**I have the image, there is enough show that I want to change.
http://i57.tinypic.com/158babt.jpg**

I have tried many options, changing stringFormat, but unfortunately it does not work. What am I doing wrong, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#jqChart').bind('dataPointLabelCreating', function (event, data) {
                data.text = data.context.dataItem[0];
            });


            $('#jqChart').jqChart({
                legend: { visible: false },
                animation: { duration: 1 },
                series: [
                    {
                        type: 'pie',
                        fillStyles: ['#418CF0', '#FCB441', '#E0400A', '#056492', '#BFBFBF'],
                        labels: {
                            stringFormat: '%s',
                            valueType: 'dataValue',
                            font: '15px sans-serif',
                            fillStyle: 'white'
                        },
                        data: [['N', 65], ['A', 58], ['B', 30],
                        ['F', 60], ['C', 65]]
                    }
                ]
            });
```